# DateTime diff in excel (millisecond accuracy)

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have some data in csv file:

`21-05-2012 15:41:49.354 | 21-05-2012 15:41:54.376|`

their format is `general`

how can I calculate in excel the dateTime diff between the two columns?

(millisecond accuracy is required)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also made the experience that Excel ignores the milliseconds part of date values in certain cases. The best solution I can suggest is importing the date values as text an then convert to dates using a formula like

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A1;19))+VALUE(RIGHT(A1;3)/86400000)
```

Once you have the values including the milliseconds part calculating the difference shouldn't be a problem, right? (E.g. with `=(Value1-Value2)*86400` to get the difference in seconds.)